# Shaping image pixel by pixel in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

So the idea is that I have and image recorded from cylindrical camera through a rectangular window in it. Image we get is a rectangular picture though it must be circular. I'm using OpenCV to move image pixel by pixel, line by line into a circle from a given rectangular picture. Problem is that pixel distribution is uneven depending on a radius. What algorithm you'd suggest to make distribution more even? Here's the code:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {


Mat src = imread( "srcImg.jpg", 1 );
Mat dst = imread( "dstImg.jpg", 1 );

int srcH = src.rows; int srcW = src.cols;
int dstH = dst.rows; int dstW = src.cols;

//convert chamber radius to pixels
double alpha, alpha_double, alpha_triple;
int r = 1500;
double k = 210 / (500 * PI);
int l = 1;
//take pixels from source and arrange them into circles

    for (int i = srcH - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= srcW ; j++) {
            alpha = (double) (2 * PI * (r * k + i)) / j;
            alpha_double = (double) (2 * PI * ((r + 15) * k + i)) / j;
            alpha_triple = alpha_double = (double) (2 * PI * ((r + 30) * k + i)) / j;

            int x_new = abs((int) (dstW / 2 - (r * k + i) * cos(alpha)) - 200);
            int y_new = abs((int) (dstH / 2 - (3.5*(r * k + i)  * sin(alpha))) + 1000);

            int x_new_double = abs((int) (dstW / 2 - (r * k + i) * cos(alpha_double)) - 200);
            int y_new_double = abs((int) (dstH / 2 - (3.5*(r * k + i)  * sin(alpha_double))) + 1000);

            int x_new_triple = abs((int) (dstW / 2 - (r * k + i) * cos(alpha_triple)) - 200);
            int y_new_triple = abs((int) (dstH / 2 - (3.5*(r * k + i)  * sin(alpha_triple))) + 1000);

            dst.at<uchar>(x_new, y_new) = src.at<uchar>(srcH - i, srcW - j);
            dst.at<uchar>(x_new_double, y_new_double) = src.at<uchar>(srcH - i, srcW - j);
            dst.at<uchar>(x_new_triple, y_new_triple) = src.at<uchar>(srcH - i, srcW - j);
        }
    }

//make dst image grey and show all images
Mat dstGray;
cvtColor(dst, dstGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
imshow("Source", src);
imshow("Result", dstGray);

waitKey();
return 0;
```

And the [image: result]

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what is the circular result you want to achieve? Like, why, what's the point and what do you expect

Comment: usually you would do the reverse. For every pixel in the target image you should calculate the value in the source image. If you calculate the positions to a sub-pixel degree you can then also apply interpolation techniques to your hearts desire.

Comment: @Eric There is a cylindrical camera and a detonational wave that runs around in it. We capture it on video through small rectangular window and connect frames of a video in one pic to get long image of every moment inside camera. The image we get is a rectangle but the camera with a wave in it is a circle, so we need to shape rectangular image to fit it into a circle of given radius so it will represent wave shape correctly. Simply we need to take every line of pixels and make a circle. I'll link original image so it will be more clear [link](https://s3.postimg.org/6gdezqppf/src_Img.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly a full answer, but I would try some kind of projection mapping instead of manually accessing every pixel. There must be an openCV way to create a destination shape then say : "Take my original image and make it fit the destination shape"

This is rather trivial for rectangles as [you can see here](https://ramsrigoutham.com/2014/06/14/perspective-projection-with-homography-opencv/), but your hole in the middle makes it harder.

Comment: _There must be an openCV way_ there is not! Unless you code it yourself

Comment: It is pretty hard to explain scientific experiment in details using two sentences but thanks, I'll try that.